# How to show/hide columns using info path, based if the login user is inside a SharePoint security group or not

Tags: 2013, infopath, custom-form, infopath-rules, forms-library

I have the following form inside my SharePoint 2013 Issue tracking tool, which I edited using info path:-

[image]

But I want to hide the last three columns , unless the login user is inside a SharePoint user group named “Issue Tracking manager”.

So can anyone advice if this is achievable using info path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

You can add Last three field in section (Containers). After adding fields in section, add rules to this section to display only when login user is inside a SharePoint user group.

You can add data connection having SharePoint user group there. And validate the same using rule applied in section.

The blog http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/05/infopath-list-form-hidedisable-fields-based-on-sharepoint-group-membership/ can help you  about it.

Comment: seems that the approach mentioned in the link yuor provide did not work with some users, as mentioned in the comments... also it is talking about SP 2010 , while i am using SP 2013

Comment: Steps will be same for Infopath 2013 too. For better understanding, here are some best url
[link1](http://www.sharepointbasic.com/2011/11/infopath-form-hidedisable-fields-based.html)
[link2](http://info.akgroup.com/blog-0/bid/69277/InfoPath-Restrict-visibility-to-users-in-a-SharePoint-Group)
[link3](http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=172)